# 405 Not Allowed in Production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express

[link to repo](https://github.com/TurtleWolfe/devOps)
[link to bug report](https://github.com/TurtleWolfe/devOps/issues/4)

I've been following [Lama Dev's Social Networking Tutorial](https://youtu.be/pFHyZvVxce0?t=7399)
but running it in docker containers, which he doesn't do in the tutorial. One of those containers is Traefik, which acts as a gateway for 80 and 443 and one more for an admin panel, but I haven't opened 8800 for the API because I was under the understanding that React should still see it in docker's default network, I'm not sure if the 405 is coming from the API or if that's still in React, what I've read on 405 says it's usually in the client and the line that logs the error is in React but it's in a failed call, so maybe the 405 message is an Axios response, it's saying the connection isn't allowed. I'm not sure what else to try changing?

It seems to work fine locally in Development But not in Production, It's usually up at [https:geoLARP.com](http://https:geoLARP.com), if it's down for a few minutes I'm probably trying a rebuild on the server and it'll be back up shortly.

I've also wondered if I need to remove `CORS`, he has them in the repo but never mentions them in the video..

The only environment variable from **dev** to **prod** that I think might make a difference is **LOCAL_HOST**, I'm changing it to **geolarp.com**, should I be including the `HTTP://` too?

[image: Screenshot from 2021-10-11 13-00-14]

```sh
export DEV_MAIL=janeDOE@mail.com
export LOCAL_HOST=localhost
export MongoDB_PASSWORD=butterzCUPz
export MongoDB_USERNAME=janeDOE
export WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
export WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=exampledb
export WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=examplepass
export WORDPRESS_DB_USER=exampleuser
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans
```

I started to try through PostMan, but currently, I've not left the API open to the public, I was expecting React would see it over the docker default network by just changing the proxy to the API container. so I've changed `localhost:8800` to `mernlama:8800` in an `.env` file
[image: Screenshot from 2021-10-11 12-20-45]

**Regist.jsx**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import "./register.css";

export default function Register() {
  const username = useRef();
  const email = useRef();
  const password = useRef();
  const passwordAgain = useRef();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(email.current.value);
    if (passwordAgain.current.value !== password.current.value) {
      passwordAgain.current.setCustomValidity('PassWords do not Match');
    } else {
      const user = {
        username: username.current.value,
        email: email.current.value,
        password: password.current.value,
      };
      try {
        await axios.post("/auth/register", user);
        history.push("/login");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="loginWrapper">
        <div className="loginLeft">
          <h3 className="loginLogo">geoLARP</h3>
          <span className="loginDesc">
            GeoLocated
          </span>
          <span className="loginDesc">
            Live Action Role Playing
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="loginRight">
          <form className="loginBox" onSubmit={handleClick} >
            <input
              placeholder="Username"
              required
              className="loginInput"
              ref={username}
            />
            <input
              placeholder="please use a disposable Email"
              type='email'
              required
              className="loginInput"
              ref={email}
            />
            <input
              placeholder="Password"
              type='password'
              required
              minLength="6"
              className="loginInput"
              ref={password}
            />
            <input
              placeholder="Password Again"
              type='password'
              required
              className="loginInput"
              ref={passwordAgain}
            />
            <button className="loginButton" type='submit' >Sign Up</button>
            <button className="loginRegisterButton">
              Log into Account
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**expressAPI/routes/auth.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// REGISTER
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    // generate a salty password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    // create a new user
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    // save the user and respond
    const user = await newUser.save();
    console.log(user);
    res.status(200)
      // .json({ message: 'Registered User with API AUTH Route', user: user._id });
      .json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }

}); // GET /api/auth


// LOGIN
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // find the user
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    // check if the user exists
    !user && res.status(404).json('User not found');


    // check if the password is correct
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validPassword && res.status(400).json('Invalid Password');

    // respond with the user
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
}); // GET /api/auth/login

module.exports = router;
// export default router;
```

[image: Screenshot from 2021-10-11 11-39-44]
[image: Screenshot from 2021-10-11 11-40-19]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your `Register.jsx`, you are requesting the backend server like

```
await axios.post("/auth/register/",user )
```

You have to specify your rest API exactly. for example, if your backend API is `localhost:8080/api/users/auth/register` you have to specify in your request.

##### Solution :

create a variable on `.env`:

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL = your backend url ( localhost:8080/api/users )
```

then call it on `Register.jsx`:

```
await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL+"auth/register" , user )
```